# Calculate a price with 3 steppers

Tags: swift, uistepper

I have created an application that displays the prices of bus tickets.
I use 3 steppers to increment the prices. There are the teenagers prices at $0.75, the seniors prices at $2.00, and the adults prices at $3.00. The goal is to be able to add and calculate teen, senior, and adult prices in the same label.
My current code only allows me to calculate for one category at a time. But I can't combine and calculate all 3 price categories in the same label.

Here is my code:

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var seniorsTicketsStepper: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var adultsTicketsStepper: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var teenagersTicketsStepper: UIStepper!

@IBOutlet weak var numOfTickets: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ticketsPrices: UILabel!

var totalPrice: Double = 0.00


@IBAction func seniorsTicketsTapped(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    updateTicketsCount(stepper: sender)
    updateTicketsPrices(stepper: sender)
}

@IBAction func adultsTicketsTapped(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    updateTicketsCount(stepper: sender)
    updateTicketsPrices(stepper: sender)
}

@IBAction func teenagersTicketsTapped(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    updateTicketsCount(stepper: sender)
    updateTicketsPrices(stepper: sender)
}


func updateTicketsCount(stepper: UIStepper) {
    stepper.maximumValue = 10
    let summe: Int = Int(seniorsTicketsStepper.value + adultsTicketsStepper.value + teenagersTicketsStepper.value)
    
    if stepper.value < 1 {
        numOfTickets.text = summe.description
        validateButton.isEnabled = false
        validateButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 170/250, green: 170/250, blue: 170/250, alpha: 1)
    } else {
        numOfTickets.text = summe.description
        validateButton.isEnabled = true
        validateButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0/250, green: 194/250, blue: 166/250, alpha: 1)
    }
}

func updateTicketsPrices(stepper: UIStepper) {
    var price = totalPrice
    
    if teenagersTicketsStepper.value != 0 {
        price += 0.75
    }
    
    if seniorsTicketsStepper.value != 0 {
        price += 2.00
    }
    
    if adultsTicketsStepper.value != 0 {
        price += 3.00
    }
    
    price = price * stepper.value
    
    ticketsPrices.text = "$ \(price.description)"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> But I can't combine and calculate all 3 price categories in the same label.

Because you don't *have* three price categories. In fact, you have no prices at all. You have only interface objects. You've completely omitted to give your view controller a place to store *data*.

Basically, you're storing your data in the interface, which is totally wrong. The interface is for *displaying* data. Storing data is something your *code* (meaning your objects) must do.

Take some time and think about what your program actually does — not what the user does or sees, but what the program's reasoning would be even if there were no user interface at all. What information does it manipulate? Once you've got instance properties for all the information you're trying to keep track of, the answer to your problem will fall into your lap.

A further hint: code like this is completely wrong:

```
if teenagersTicketsStepper.value != 0 {
    price += 0.75
}

if seniorsTicketsStepper.value != 0 {
    price += 2.00
}

if adultsTicketsStepper.value != 0 {
    price += 3.00
}
```

Once you've got your categories, perhaps even expressed as an object type, that sort of "choice" will happen without magic numbers being embedded in tedious logic.

Comment: Yes, I know I still have a lot to learn because I am a beginner in coding. I know I have to learn MVC to better understand the structure of my application. I will start there. Thank you for your comments.